# Additive error model for non-linear case

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, nonlinear, noise

I have checked other questions regarding additive noise model, but I could not convince myself for non-linear case. Assume the data vector $\mathbf{d}$ is described by a possibly non-linear deterministic model $f(\mathbf{m})$:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{d} = f(\mathbf{m}) + \mathbf{\eta},
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{\eta}$ is a Gaussian noise with mean $\mathbf{0}$ and the covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ (i.e., $ \mathbf{\eta} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$). Why can we say the likelifood Prob($\mathbf{d}|\mathbf{m}$) $\propto \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} (f(\mathbf{m}) - \mathbf{d})^T \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} (f(\mathbf{m}) - \mathbf{d})\right)$? It looks like the $\eta$ in the Gaussian distribution is just replaced by $f(\mathbf{m}) - \mathbf{d}$, but I could not understand why this process is valid. Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Because $\eta=\mathbf{d}-f(\mathbf m),$ the usual rules of algebra apply and permit you to substitute one for the other.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that Prob($\mathbf{\eta}$) $\propto \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}( f(\mathbf{m}) - \mathbf{d})^T \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} ( f(\mathbf{m}) - \mathbf{d})\right)$ by substitution, but I cannot understand why we can say Prob($\mathbf{\eta}$) = Prob($\mathbf{d}$|$\mathbf{m}$) from there. To me, Prob($\mathbf{\eta}$) = Prob($\mathbf{d}$ - f($\mathbf{m}$))

Comment: I don't see that equation being made anywhere. Moreover, when working with the likelihood you *must* express it in terms of what you know (the data $\mathbf d$ and $\mathbf m$).  Keeping the expression in terms of $\eta,$ as you have just written, would be useless, because you don't observe $\eta.$

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I see, we do not observe $\eta$... If possible, could you show me how to substitute one for the other to get Prob(d|m)? I think this is so obvious for some people, so explicit explanations are rerely found.

Comment: It literally is the elementary rule of arithmetic: by virtue of asserting $a=b,$ everywhere "$a$" appears in a formula you may substitute "$b.$"

Comment: This is what I tried in the above comment. If I replaced $\eta$ with $f(\mathbf{m}) - \mathbf{d}$, I obtained the resulting probability on the right hand side. However, for the left hand side, I got Prob($f(\mathbf{m}) - \mathbf{d}$), not Prob($\mathbf{d}$|$m$)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134090/discussion-between-t-b-and-whuber).